# Flutter: Unstoppable Notification, FCM, Flutter Local Notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I would like to know if there is any possible way to create an unstoppable notification in the flutter, so when user open the app, the notification will stop? Also, how can we make the notification so it will not get overridden by another app?

I would like to make the notification always ringing until the user opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Firebase documentation, you'll see there are two [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options):

> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
> - Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

So notification messages are handled by the system, which only displays them when the app is **not** active. If the user is using the app, it doesn't display the notification but *does* deliver it to your code.

The easiest way to ensure the message is always displayed consistently, is to let your code handle its display. So send a **data** message, and write the code to [handle foreground and background messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#message_handling) and display a local notification.

Comment: Thank you for the hint Mr.Frank, i know what to do with my code now. Let me try it, and i will post it if i find a good way to solve my problem.